# FilterRow is not populated in Janus.GridEx

Tags: c#, gridex

I am working on a manual filtering solution for `Janus.GridEx`.

```
gridEX1.FilterMode = FilterMode.Manual;
```

We need to query our database everytime that filter changes and we need to do that everytime user types something in filter row so we have :

```
gridEX1.FilterRowUpdateMode=FilterRowUpdateMode.WhenValueChanges;
```

To implement manual filtering I have handled `ApplyFiltering` event like this :

```
gridEX1.ApplyingFilter += (sender, e) =>
            {
                if (gridEX1.RootTable.Columns[gridEX1.Col].Key != "CustomerName") return;
                var customerName = gridEX1.GetValue(gridEX1.Col);

                gridEX1.SuspendBinding();
                bindingSource1.DataSource= string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(customerName.ToString()) ? _customers : _customers.Where(c => c.CustomerName.Contains(customerName.ToString())).ToList();
                gridEX1.ResumeBinding();


            };
```

As you can see I am using `GetValue` method because when we set update mode to `WhenValueChanges` filter row is not populated.
The problem here is : since `RowFilter` is not updated , when the datasource changes grid loads its previous row filter which in turn clears the character that user has already typed.

How I can force `GridEx` to fill `FilterRow` in `WhenValueChanges`  mode ?

Comment: Can you plan to enforce the new filter in the Data Source instead of relying on GridEx, which is picking up the old value, this would certainly not use GridEx filtering capability, but a workaround, or is it feasible to save new RowFilter separately in a variable and enforcing it on GridEx post loading with the new DataSource, though this will lead to repetitive and redundant call, but may serve the purpose

Comment: Check out this too, suggestion is similar to mine, but it talks about canceling event post applying new filter manually

http://www.infragistics.com/community/forums/t/16234.aspx

Comment: @MrinalKamboj we would like to use the same approach  for filtering so that our customers don't have to change their behavior.